# CSS non-wrapping floating divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to create a single line containing a variable amount of (floating?) divs: the container dimension is fixed, and it is supposed to add an horizontal scrollbar when needed, never wrapping.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work: it wraps instead.

```
div#sub {
    background-image:url("../gfx/CorniceSotto.png");
    width:760px;
    height:190px;
}
div#sub > div#ranking {
    position:relative;
    top:42px;
    left:7px;
    width:722px;
    height:125px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
div#sub > div#ranking > div.player {
    float:left;
    width:67px;
    height:120px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color:#f3e1bb;
}
```

I've tried a few things (inline,table-cell,etc.) but they all failed.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: can you set up a fiddle at jsfiddle.net with your example?

Comment: @Mathletics: here it is! http://jsfiddle.net/HZzrk/

Comment: Hi. What does '>' mean in CSS?

Comment: @bodacydo (an anyone coming later) `Direct Child Selector` - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`and give the container `white-space: nowrap`.

```
div#sub > div#ranking {
    position:relative;
    top:42px;
    left:7px;
    width:722px;
    height:125px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div#sub > div#ranking > div.player {
    display: inline-block;
    width:67px;
    height:120px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color:#f3e1bb;
}
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/3/

Comment: Without changing the `width` to `min-width` like in my answer, then you still get a "wrapping" of elements if you get too many. See your fiddle with some extra elements: http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/2/

Comment: cool! I tried both `inline-block` and `nowrap`, but not together!

Comment: Actually, that is an issue in my answer too. The `min-width` does not totally resolve it.

Comment: @Scott: my fiddle had a mistake, updated it, sorry. the code in the answer was correct.

Comment: It needs both `inline-block` like Daniel and `min-width` like my answer.

Comment: It needs `inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` as shown in my answer, no `min-width` at all.

Comment: Ah, you tricked me :-). Your original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D5hUu/1/ that you posted forgot the `nowrap` and I missed that, so it appeared to not be working. +1 for correcting that (even if it did through me for a confusion in thinking it did not work).

Comment: @John Kurlak: add `vertical-align: bottom;` to `div#sub > div#ranking > div.player`

Comment: using ie6 won't display it correctly, that's right, but using this outdated browser, a wrong displayed website is not the most significant problem for the user ;-)

Comment: Beware when setting `display` to `inline-block`. It causes unnecessary spaces between items if there are any in-between whitespaces.

Comment: Also set `font-size:0` to the wrapper to remove unwanted white spaces between children.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of how to make floating elements not wrap.

Answer (score 6):

inline won't work, table-cell should work - see this jsFiddle I made in answer to a similar question:

http://jsfiddle.net/DxZbV/1/

won't work in <=ie7 though...

Answer (score 4):

whoops, I misread the question. Previous answer removed.

---

on your container, `white-space: nowrap` and then on the elements `display: inline-block`

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HZzrk/1/

Comment: no, `scroll` means "scrollbar always present", while `auto` means "scrollbar only if needed"

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: Combined DanielB's and my original answer. You need to put `min-width` instead of `width` for both `sub` and `ranking` and have the elements set to `inline-block` with container having `white-space: nowrap`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5wRXw/3/

**Edit 2**: For your purposes, it might be better to eliminate the `overflow` properties all together on the `ranking` element. See http://jsfiddle.net/5wRXw/4/

```
#sub {
    backgrond-color: yellow;
    min-width:760px;
    height:190px;
}
#ranking {
    position:relative;
    top:42px;
    left:7px;
    min-width:722px;
    height:125px;
    overflow-x:auto; /* you may be able to eliminate this see fiddle above */
    overflow-y:hidden; /* and eliminate this */
    white-space: nowrap; /* like DanielB */
}
#ranking > .player {
    display: inline-block; /* like DanielB */
    width:67px;
    height:120px;
    margin-left:5px;
    background-color:#f3e1bb;
}
```

Comment: Mhm quote from OP `the container dimension is fixed`: So `min-width` is not a solution.