# Unordered list with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

I want to have a UL list, but with its elements floating left and list to have fixed height and width.

What I have now:

```
ul { 
width: 230px;
height: 30px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

li { 
float: left;
display: inline 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="dev">
  <li>el</li>
  <li>el</li>
</ul>
```

Elements float alright, but scrollbar doesn't work (greyed out) and elements are going to new line. What can I do?

Comment: post your complete code here........

Comment: I don't think you need it, since I have problem with this list only, but I added HTML to my question.

Comment: @Vucko: it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS non-wrapping floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447553/css-non-wrapping-floating-divs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `white-space` property to `nowrap` on the list, and then disable `float: left` on the list elements.

```
ul { 
  /* ... */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li { 
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That's a brilliant find! I know this is old but if anyone can explain the reason for removing float to make it work then that would be interesting!

Comment: @Imdad If elements are floated, they are no longer flowed as a single line of text with whitespace separators (i.e. the `display: inline` isn't doing anything). If you remove that, you can use the `white-space` attribute to dictate what should happen at whitespace delimiters when the content is longer than the container.

Comment: Fair! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
ul {
    width: 230px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```