# Why do div float left inside the body tag wrap

Tags: html, css

In this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpuv/

Why do the `<div` with float:left inside body wrap around to a new line?

I want them to all float left without any wrapping and a scrollbar should appear on the bottom of the page, but what happens is not what I expected.

Comment: You want scrollbar to appear at the bottom, and everything should be in a single line. Isn't it?

Comment: A single horizontal line, yes.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpuv/2/

```
body {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.floatMe {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: put a width on the body tag? but I could have any number of div elements.

Comment: Why does this work, there's no float left? ... also - if the elements have variable heights they don't align at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok on .floatMe adding vertical-align: top helps

Comment: `inline-block` acts as both an `inline element`: no line breaks/clears and a `block element`: allows you to specify margins, padding, width, height, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can check below - seems to be what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpuv/3/

```
body {
   overflow-x:scroll;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

#parent {
   white-space: nowrap;
}

#parent div {
    display: inline-block;
}



 < div id="parent>
        ....all the divs with no style...
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpuv/

```
div{clear:both;float:left; overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of float as this previous solution suggests:
[CSS non-wrapping floating divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447553/css-non-wrapping-floating-divs)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` for all div's.
Check this Fiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/dhanith/Lhpuv/7/