# Nested div elements wrapping with float left

Tags: css

I have four nested div elements with `float:left` and the fourth element is wrapping below the first due to the length of the container.

```
.container {
    width: 320px;
    height: 110px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.nested      {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;

}

<div class='container'>
<div class='nested'></div>
<div class='nested'></div>
<div class='nested'></div>
<div class='nested'></div>
</div>
```

How do I stop the wrapping so that the viewed elements are scrollable in the x axis (or even hidden/truncated)?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tku65/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447553/css-non-wrapping-floating-divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/Tku65/1/)

```
  white-space: nowrap;
```

Add this property to your container.

Try to avoid float properties. Use `display: inline-block;` in this case.

Comment: Note the addition of 'display: inline-block;' too!

Comment: Yep, that did the trick...plus display:inline-block instead of float. Many thanks!